# Custom xsl function with parameter array

Tags: vb.net, string, xslt, extension-methods, xslt-1.0

I want to create a function for XSL to resolve a text like "Inserted by {0} at {1}" in "Inserted by Admin at 2013-05-13T10:02:17". I use XSL 1.0 and define my own functions in .NET. I try this like

```vb
Public Class MyStringExtension

    Public Function Format(ByVal value As String, ByVal ParamArray args As String()) As String
        Return String.Format(value, args)
    End Function
End Class
```

```xml
<xsl:value-of select="MyStringExtensionNamespace:Format('Inserted by {0} at {1}', 'Admin', '2013-05-13T10:02:17')" />
```

It seems that the `ParamArray` option not works or perhaps is not allowed in this case. With any other function I have no problems. Is there a way to define a function which allows multiple parameters without defining for each possible one function. (something like `concat('Param 1', ' Param 2', 'Param 3', 'Param 4', 'Param 5', ...)`)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this within XSL:

```
<func:function name = "formatMyString">
  <xsl:param name="firstParam" />
  <xsl:param name="secondParam" />
  <func:result select="concat('Inserted by ', $firstParam,' at ', $secondparam)"/>
</func:function>
```

Comment: This is a possibility for this example. But I need something general for other strings which also contains some place holders.

Comment: If you define your params as `<xsl:param name="firstParam" select="null"/>` you should be able to use any number of placeholders you like. You don't have to hand all parameters to the function in XSLT, just the ones you use.